# Problem with permissions when sharing a mounted filesystem

Tags: mount, samba, lvm

I am setting up a linux to act as a fileserver, using CentOS 6.3.

Since I want to have disk quotas and can't install LVM (it is a 32 bit machine), I am using an LVM volume with ext4 mounted as `/samba/seg`

I have created `/samba/seg`, assigned a domain group, changed FS permissions to 770, executed:

- `semanage fcontext -a -t samba_share_t /samba/seg`
- `restorecon -R -v /samba/seg`

My config (from `testparm`):

```
[seg]
       comment = Remote unit
       path = /samba/seg
       valid users = @DOMAIN\GROUP
       read only = No
       create mask = 0660
       force create mode =  0660
       directory mask = 0770
       force directory mode = 0770
       hide unreadable = Yes
       access based share enum = Yes
```

When I try to connect from a Windows box (logged as domain user) I get a message stating that I have no access rights to the share. I have to make `setenforce Permissive` in order to access the share.

The domain configuration seems ok. I can login with a domain user, check users of domain groups and so on.

In the other hand, I just did create a directory (not a filesystem) in `/samba/test` and replied the steps with it; it worked without problem so the issue seems to be when sharing a mounted filesystem.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my bad. I keep repassing the process, and investigating what did the instructions do.

When looking at `semanage` found `ls -Z` and I found that the samba_share_t permission/object/whatever was not sticking to the mounted filesystem.

What I did was change `fstab` to add a mount option, now it reads

```
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_seg       /samba/seg    ext4    context="system_u:object_r:samba_share_t:s0" 1 2
```

That did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

> - `semanage fcontext -a -t samba_share_t /samba/seg`

Replace the above command with this one:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t samba_share_t /samba/seg(/.*)?
```

E.g. see Procedure 5.8. Changing a Directory and its Contents Types" at https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security-enhanced_linux/sect-security-enhanced_linux-selinux_contexts_labeling_files-persistent_changes_semanage_fcontext